# CKEDITOR : Wiris plugin Causing Issue

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wiris

I'm using Wiris plugin for handling math Equations and all.

The official site of the WIRIS plugin is given below.

[Wiris plugin page for CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/ckeditorwiris)

[Wiris plugin ckeditor Demo](http://www.wiris.com/plugins/demo/ckeditor/java/)

** Problem:**

Whenever I'm using the wiris plugin it replaces the whole content(**Because It needs to convert all MathML equation to IMG tag with SVG-base64 Image**).

I'm using a lot of custom plugins which depends on event's that made in the document like click,keydown,keyup.

I try to found the solution but I can't.Can anyone please help me with this.